# Mapping route history

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to display a route, that consists of 1,000-2,000 (lat/lon) points.

I tried to do this, but I do not think it is a good solution to show route for so many points; please advise on best way to do it.

```
function calcRoute() {    
    var request = {
        origin:new google.maps.LatLng(37, -97),
        waypoints: [
        {
            location:new google.maps.LatLng(39, -97),
            stopover:false
        },{
            location:new google.maps.LatLng(32, -95),
            stopover:false
        }],
        destination:new google.maps.LatLng(37, -97),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };    

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The most likely solution is that you, as the map expert need to devise an algorithm that displays enough information to the user while simultaneously not cluttering the map so much that information is obscured. Very common problem in mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the entire result to the DirectionsRenderer you can use the overview_path, (which is simplified), of the [**google.maps.DirectionsRoute**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRoute) object and add the polylines directly to the map, for example:

```
directionsService.route(request,plot);


function plot(result,status){
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        for (var n = 0 ;n < result.routes.length ; n++ ){
            addLine(result.routes[n].overview_path);
        }
    }
}

function addLine(path){
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline ({
    path: path,
    map: map
    });
}
```